# How do i count a fluctuating 22.1v (11.5v) pulse from reed switch with Arduino?

Tags: arduino, pulse, reed-switch

It has come to my attention that my first description of my problem was very cryptic, so I have tried to rewrite it for better understanding.

I have an actuator that measures 8 pulses/rpm and there is 440 pulses in a stroke, the stroke length is 250mm and the speed of the actuator is 20mm/s which equals to 28,4 ms/pulse while running.

The actuator can accidentally stop with the reed switch activated and so there is 22.1V and 2,55mA running through it. (if not the signal is ofc. 0v).

When the actuator is running the signal drops to 11.5V and 1,35mA I need to get both these values down to a level that the Arduino can handle, which means that for the Arduino to see both signals as high they should be above 3v and under 5v.

Is this correct?

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll need a little more information before we know what to do. What do you plan to do with the 4.7V? Is it to be a power supply for some logic parts? i.e. does it want to be a DC signal? if yes, then what is the load on that power rail? If you are powering some simple logic parts, then its probably pretty small, maybe a few milli-amps.

You need to know the load current so you can pick the resistor value to put before the zener diode as the resistor will have both the load current and the diode current flowing through it.

As for the capacitor, it depends on the AC response of the zener diode. The capacitor is a low pass filter so it will smooth out the voltage changes that the diode will see. the 3db frequency for the filter is 1/(2*pi*R*C) and you typically would choose a frequency that is 1/10 of the frequency you are trying to filter out. so this depends on how often the signal on the 24V line is changing.

Comment: I'm going to input the 4.7V into a pin on the Arduino and count the pulses.

Comment: I'm not quite sure as to how often the signal goes on and off, but from calculation one stroke takes 12,5 seconds and with 440 pulses in a stroke, there should be a pulse every 28,4 ms

Comment: OK. That's not what i thought you were doing with the signal. So you want to take a series of pulses that go between 22.1V and 11.5V and translate the levels to be compatible as an input to an Arduino? assuming that the Arduino is running at 5V, typical input logic levels would be "above 2V" for a high, and "below 0.8V" for a low. Do I have this right? if yes then a zener diode is completely useless...

Comment: I want to count the pulses, so that I can control the actuator movement. But to do that I have to reduce the "high" voltage from the feed down to 5 volts or under, so that the arduino can handle it and there is where my question starts.

Comment: Yes excactly. You have got it now :-)

Comment: The Arduino will read a 0 if the voltage on the input pin is under 3 volt http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Constants

Comment: So how would u suggest I do?

Comment: so all you need is a simple resistor voltage divider. if you use a 11:1 ratio, you get 22/11=2V for the high level and 11/11=1V for the low level. Most logic parts will see this is a high and low logic level (but I have not tried this with an Arduino so can't be certain). Most parts have their threshold somewhere between 2V and 1V.

so use a 10k series resistor and a 1K to ground.

Comment: I would also put a 100nF cap across the 1K to reduce any high frequency noise that might get picked up. And also consider a clamp diode to 5V on the Arduino input as protection. This is not required but good design practice when you have higher voltages that could damage the input of the receiving device.

Comment: The problem is that both 22.1v and 11.5V are ment as high levels (the reed switch is activated) but the actuator draws so much current that the voltages drops. also the arduino sees 3v and under as a LOW.

Comment: OK. we are having a COMMUNICATION problem here. As an EE, and now manager, for 35+ years, the hardest skill to find is an engineer who can clearly describe the technical details of the problem.
so PLEASE describe your problem in terms of the "input signal" and desired "output signal". I'm tired of guessing...

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not an EE and English isn't my first language, so it wasn't my intention to be cryptic.

Comment: I have an actuator that measures 8 pulses/rpm and there is 440 pulses in a stroke, the stroke length is 250mm and the speed of the actuator is 20mm/s which equals to 28,4 ms/pulse while running.

The actuator can accidentally stop with the reed switch activated and so there is 22.1V and 2,55mA running through it. (if not the signal is ofc. 0v).

When the actuator is running the signal drops to 11.5V and 1,35mA 

I need to get both these numbers down to a level that the Arduino can handle, which means that for the Arduino to see both signals as high they should be above 3v and under 5v.

Comment: So to confirm: the input signal has a low voltage of 0V, and a variable high voltage that is above 11.5V, and can be as high is 22.1V. 
You want an output signal that is compatible with an Arduino logic input pin. High input should be above 3V (I bet 2V would work also) and low input below 1V (guessing on this one but thats fairly common).
Did I get this right?

Comment: Yes. the reed switch just opens and closes to make a pulse and can sometimes land on a closed position which gives the higher output since the actuator isn't running. the input on the Arduino should make the Arduino read a high value and per the documentation on the Arduino homepage the high level is interpreted between 3V and 5V.

Comment: so the low voltage is already at 0V so nothing needed there (actually what sets that voltage? is there a pulldown on the reed switch? you might need a 10K pulldown to set the voltage when the switch is open).
so your initial idea of using a zener is fine. you need to size things for the worst case which is the 22V input. You can use a zener anywhere between 3 and 5V. Lets assume a 4V zener. so you need to drop 22-4 = 18V in the resistor. continued in next comment...

Comment: Let's also assume the diode can handle 500mW of power (thats fairly typical but check the datasheet for the part). so max current through the diode is 0.5W / 4V = 125mA. so the resistor max current must be that current: R=V/I so R=18V/125mA=144ohms so any resistor larger than 144ohms will work. Lets use a 1Kohm.

Comment: Then the current in the resistor and diode is: 18V/1Kohm=18mA, well below 125mA. power dissipated in the resistor is W=V*I=18V*18mA=324mW so a 1/2watt resistor will work fine.

Comment: Lastly, if you can't find a zener diode you can use standard silicon diodes which drop 0.7V nominally and stack up 5 of them to get 3.5V. that might also be cheaper as diodes are pretty cheap.

Comment: one last thing: do you need a capacitor across the zener? only if there is high frequency noise in the circuit. The diode is fairly capacitive so will provide some low pass filtering, but you can always put a 1uF cap for a time constant of R*C=1K*1uF=1msec. That will pass your 28msec signals just fine but block higher frequency noise.

Comment: I was thinking of using a 4.7V zener, as it is available to me in both 0.5W, 1.3W and 5W, is there a need to bigger than 0,5w?. 
So by using your calculations I get:

22.1v-4.7v=17.4v and
0.5W/4.7V=106.4mA and 
17.4v/106,4=163,7ohms and 
17,4v/1kohm=17,4mA and
17,4V*17,4mA=302,8mW

Comment: Using a 4.7V zener means that there is a little less power in the resistor and a little more power in the diode but not by much: power in the diode is V*I=4.7V*17.4mA=81.78mW so well within the 500mW capability of the diode.

Comment: Sir could you please look at the picture in my original post and verify that I have understood. Thank you.

Comment: that looks good. I would avoid using an electrolytic cap and just use a smaller value cap if you can't find a 1uF cap that is not electrolytic. You should also try the circuit without the cap first as its only needed to get rid of noise, if there is any noise present.

Comment: Can't seem to find any ceramic caps, will a tantalum cap work? and if so, is the capacity critical? or could I if I understood it correctly use up to an like 25uF if the resistor is 1kohm? I mean as long as i keep under 28ms.

Comment: If you want to measure a 28msec pulse you want the time constant of the filter to be about 1/10th of that value. a 25usec time constant would start to distort the waveform you are trying to measure. keep the cap smaller is possible. tantalum will work but they are also polarized and will blow up if exposed to overvoltage.

Comment: I understand. Will try without, but with the prices so low and I have to order the parts in anyway, I might as well get a cap just in case. I will try and find a suitable cap 1/10th of the 28ms. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: One last question, I have found one 1uF/50v and one 2.2uF/50V electrolytic cap in my stash, are they usable?

Comment: yup. should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a diode and a resistor.

The diodes cathode should be connected to the 24V signal line and the anode is to be connected to the arduino & pulled up to the arduino 4.7V rail via a 10k resistor.